# Как защитить Ajax запрос от спама.

Tags: php, ajax

У меня такая проблема получилась. Есть простенький скрипт который анализирует некие данные стороннего сайта и как только там они поменялись то отправляет запрос Ajax на php скрипт которые пишет все в базу данных.
Но если узнать куда отправляются данные то можно спамить запросами и испортить как базу так и загрузить её. 
Как мне сделать так чтоб данный php скрипт через Ajax  мог запускать только сам сайт?

Answer (score 0):

Если скрипт расположен на сервере с постоянным IP, то как минимум сделайте ограничение по IP - принимайте запросы только от белого списка IP-адресов.

Ведите лог-файл запросов.

Контролируйте частоту запросов: если их стало слишком много - блокируйте.

Выдавайте доступ только зарегистрированным пользователям и в запросе передавайте токен аутентификации или JWT-токен.